# list inside list python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am not looking to get an list inside list instead I just want to add zeros but do not know how. see code

```
def  myconv(x,h):
    q=[]
    print(h)
    for i in range(len_h):
        q.append(h[len_h-1-i])
    print(q)
    q.insert(0,([0]*len_h))       #I want this to add just plain zeros to the array... not an array insdie an
                                  #like it is doing here
    q.insert(len(q)+1,(0]*len_h))  

    print(q)

print(myconv([6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]))
```

Comment: Just another helper, instead of `q.insert(len(q)+1` you can just do `q.append(`

Comment: You are using lists here. They can be used as arrays, but are more flexible.

Comment: can you add an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `+`, e.g. `[0, 0, 0] + [2, 1, 3] == [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3]`, to concatenate an array onto the first. Otherwise, you'll need to insert (or append) items one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate how list multiplication works:

```
>>> [0]*2
[0, 0]
>>> [0]*5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I prefer the in-place extend operation. Just don't assign to it, because like most all Python in-place methods, it returns None.

```
>>> l2.extend([0]*5)
>>> l2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this:

```
q = [0]*len_h + q
```

*or*

```
q[0:0] = [0]*len_h
```